# How do i put something at the end of my effect in spark ar studio?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put a ''Thank you for using our effect'' at the end of my Effect, but i dont know where to put the plane in my patch editor. the plane is ready I need help for the patch editor please.`[enter code here][1]`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood maybe you just have to control the Visible property of the plane using the patch editor, not the plane itself. So after a amount of time you can set it to true.